# Get results of the search from MSSQL data base in Django web page

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have to create simple Web page which will search data in a SQL Server data base.

I managed to connect to my database and run server with my simple HTML which has Label, textbox, button and listbox. Expect this, project has default settings.

Could you please help me, how can i set request to DB like `"Select * FROM Mac_Storage where MAC = "Here should be the text from textbox""` to button and return the results to my Web page?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the Django basic tutorial [Django Tutorial 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) - 7 and the `manage.py instpectdb` command [Create Models of existing database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/).